# Изменение размеров BottomSheetLayout при его вытягивании вверх

Tags: android, layout, android-bottomsheet

Всем привет! Сразу уточню, что я новичок в андроид разработке. Мне необходимо реализовать bottomSheetLayout, который изображён на картинке. Его особенность в том, что он плавно увеличивается/уменьшается в ширине по мере его выдвижения/свёртывания. Попробовал устанавливать layoutParams "match_parent" для width, но т.к. устанавливал после окончания выдвижения, то анимация получалась резкая и некрасивая.
Поэтому прошу вашей помощи или совета, где можно посмотреть про плавное изменение ширины этого layout'а.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В *BottomSheet* есть метод

```
public void onSlide(View bottomSheet, float slideOffset)
```

`slideOffset` это параметр который показывает насколько раскрыт ваш *BottomSheet* (0..1 float)

Вы можете привязаться к этому параметру и изменять размер по мере его изменения.

Comment: Сделал с помощью метода onSlide, но теперь проблема в другом - при очень резком вытягивании ширина не успевает поменяться. Как быть?

Comment: Не совсем понятно что значит не успевает? Он не отрисовывается или отрисовывается рывками?